# Rails serialized hash - is it possible to specify a data type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I'm serializing form input into a hash. Is it possible to force some of the inputs into integers?

For example, if I do @user.update_attributes(params[:user]), and one of the params is supposed to be a number, that number will get stored a string like "123".

Is it possible to make sure it is stored as an integer?

To be clear:

My User model looks like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  store :preferences, accessors: [:max_capacity]
  ...
end
```

and my form might have an input like

```
<input name="user[preferences][max_capacity]" type="text"/>
```

This will cause max_capacity to be stored as a String. Can I force it to be an integer when I store it?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the user object that is stored in the params hash directly before you save it. If you convert max_capacity from a string into an integer you will want to account for the case when a user submits a bad value for max_capacity. This can be handled with a begin/rescue block.

In your Controller action you could do the following:

```
def update
  max_capacity = params[:user][preferences][max_capacity]
  begin
    # Attempt to convert into an integer
    Integer(max_capacity)
  rescue
    # If max_capacity was incorrectly submitted: 'three', '04', '3fs'.
    redirect_to edit_user_path, :alert => "Unable to update user. Invalid max capacity."
  else
    If it can be converted, do so, and update the user object in the params hash.
    params[:user][preferences][max_capacity] = Integer(max_capacity)
  end

  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        .
        .
        .
end
```